# Как задать цвет пикселям?

Tags: c#, graphics

```
TextureBrush NoiseBrush(Color[] colors)
{
  Bitmap b = new Bitmap(128, 128);
  Random r = new Random(128);
  for (int x = 0; x <= b.Width - 1; x++) 
 {
  for (int y = 0; y <= b.Height - 1; y++) 
  {
    b.SetPixel(x, y, colors(r.Next(colors.Length)));
  }
}
TextureBrush T = new TextureBrush(b);
b.Dispose();
return T;
}
```

Мне выдаёт ошибку:

---

"colors" является "переменная", но используется как "метод"

Решение: `b.SetPixel(x, y, colors[r.Next(colors.Length)]);`

**Обновление**

Теперь когда пытаюсь вызвать его у меня не получается присвоить цвет:

```
TextureBrush bodygb = NoiseBrush(
{
  Color.FromArgb(34, 29, 23),
  Color.FromArgb(50, 45, 39)
});
```

Как через массив добавить цвет?

Comment: Ну, `colors` у вас массив? А вы поставили круглые скобки, для чего?

Comment: @VladD, оу, не заметил, видимо так нужно: `b.SetPixel(x, y, colors[r.Next(colors.Length)]);`

Comment: Да, именно так!

Comment: Обновил ответ, и добавил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на обновление: например, так:

```
TextureBrush bodygb = NoiseBrush(
    new[]
    {
        Color.FromArgb(34, 29, 23),
        Color.FromArgb(50, 45, 39)
    });
```

Альтернативно, если метод `NoiseBrush` описать так:

```
TextureBrush NoiseBrush(params Color[] colors)
```

то можно будет вызывать проще:

```
TextureBrush bodygb = NoiseBrush(
    Color.FromArgb(34, 29, 23),
    Color.FromArgb(50, 45, 39));
```

---

Ещё одна проблема с вашим кодом — использование `Random`. Вы используете всё время одно и тоже значение `seed`, а значит, результат будет всё время одинаковым. Лучше сделать так: объявить вне метода

```
static Random r = new Random();
```

и удалить создание `Random` в методе.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно)

Comment: @ArteS: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!